# keeping value fixed using span attribute in html

Tags: css, stylesheet, html

Here's my span element:

```
<span style="padding-right:20px">Reference No.<?php echo $ref_number; ?></span>
```

I want reference no. text to remain fixed. but based on the length of the value coming from db the text is moving right and left. how do i fix it?

Comment: Can you create some fiddle or share your HTML along with CSS?

Comment: *moving right and left* - you mean the width is increasing or decreasing depending on value from DB? If yes, what should be done if the value is more than the specified width? Should it be hidden?

Comment: yes. the text should be fixed(Reference No.) but on the right when the value comes that should expand the page on the right.

Comment: @user1069186: Sorry mate, I am not getting it. Can you make fiddle (or) some sort of other illustration for us to understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: Adjust a width to the `number` span to fix the `label` span:

HTML:

```
<span class="label">Reference No.</span>
<span class="number"><?php echo $ref_number; ?></span>
```

CSS:

```
span.number {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px; // maximum reference width
}
```

**See** [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/6BTrt/1/)